# Display illimited rational number defined by two integer

Tags: math, digit, rational-number

I'm working on a Rational number class in c++.
The Rational number is defined by two int (numerator and denominator).
I would like to display it properly as digit number. for now, I determine if the number is an "illimited" or a limited digit rational number.

Here is a little pseudo code to illustrate:

```
define print_rational(num, denom):
   if(isUnlimited(num, denom):
       ?
   else:
       //"limited" rational, no problem for them
```

I would like to display illimited numbers like this : print one time the repetitives digits, then "..." (Example : 1/3 -> 0.3..., 1/11 -> 0.09...)

So, is there an algorithm to find the block of digit who will be repeat in a rational number ?

Comment: long division works by a series of divisions with quotient and remainder. When the same remainder pops up a second time (as it must by the pigeon hole principle since it is between 0 and denom - 1 inclusive) the process cycles and the same block repeats. Thus, it is essentially a problem of cycle-detection.

Comment: I find the same question answered. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192070/what-is-a-efficient-way-to-find-repeating-decimal

Comment: By "digit number" do you mean a number shown with decimal digits? You do you mean by "illimited" and "limited" here? Do you mean with finitely or infinitely many decimal places--i.e. terminating versus repeating?

Comment: Sorry for my approximative "english math". Math and english are both not in my specialities !
I get my answer, I just needed that someone remind me that long division algorithm exist. I guess I should read my primary courses more often !

I'll post my code as answer to close this question once I finished it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your result into string and then apply [Longest repeated substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem) to it.